# WebRTC Peer to Peer without ICE / STUN / TURN but with SSH

Tags: ssh, webrtc, stun, turn, signaling

Let's say I have access to a server via ssh and my own laptop. However, I wish to use webrtc to transmit data via a peer connection for it's ultra low latency over UDP. It's also crucial that I have NO communication between a third server.

What I would like to do, is use ssh to get the signalling information for the two machines (offers and answers) to then create a webRTC channel. This way I can say that no information ever went to a third server (including the signalling part).

I understand the requirement is a bit silly, but it's due to how we network things currently, and the important part is the super low latency webRTC provides.

Or is this the wrong tool for the job perhaps? Open to other suggestions :)

Comment: If the ssh connection can be done without going through any jump-hosts, then the WebRTC connection shouldn't need any TURN servers either (STUN doesn't add any latency, that's just one request at the beginning, followed by direct peer communication). Also even the ssh manual says that "an SSH-based setup entails a fair amount of overhead" so it really is perhaps the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: It's not quite clear, you have 2 devices in one network and question is about signaling, how to send offer/answer between them via SSH? Or these devices are in different networks and the only communication channel they have is SSH port, so the question is about if it's possible to make peer-to-peer via this port?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to send an offer and answer between machines via SSH, so they can then be a peer to peer webrtc communication channel. I know my requirements seem silly, the issue is I want to confidently say that this communication link is completely peer to peer and has no reliance on a third server for signalling. I'll try update my question to reflect that better.